# Spring STS 3.6.1 and Gradle plugin

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I have downloaded Gradle support plugin through extension tab in dashboard of spring STS 3.6.1.

Then tried to import a local gradle based project. But when I click on the button "Build Model". The following error message pops up and gradel project can't be imported to my spring STS.

> unable to find valid certification path to requested target  See error
>   log for details

The Error log details is as follows:

> org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: unable to find valid
>   certification path to requested target    at
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleModelProvider$GroupedModelProvider.ensureModels(GradleModelProvider.java:284)
>     at
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleProject.getGradleModel(GradleProject.java:633)
>     at
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleProject.getSkeletalGradleModel(GradleProject.java:654)
>     at
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.wizards.GradleImportWizardPageOne$11.doit(GradleImportWizardPageOne.java:516)
>     at
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable.run(GradleRunnable.java:84)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
>   Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not
>   install Gradle distribution from
>   'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.0-bin.zip'.   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution.getToolingImplementationClasspath(DistributionFactory.java:107)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.CachingToolingImplementationLoader.create(CachingToolingImplementationLoader.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.create(SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.java:40)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.onStartAction(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:81)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.run(LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:48)
>     at
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleModelProvider.buildModel(GradleModelProvider.java:385)
>     at
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleModelProvider$GroupedModelProvider.ensureModels(GradleModelProvider.java:290)
>     ... 5 more Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:56)    at
>   org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:42)    at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ProgressReportingDownload.download(DistributionFactory.java:127)
>     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:57)   at
>   org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:44)    at
>   org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
>     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution.getToolingImplementationClasspath(DistributionFactory.java:103)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.CachingToolingImplementationLoader.create(CachingToolingImplementationLoader.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.create(SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.java:40)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.onStartAction(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:81)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.run(LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown
>   Source)   ... 31 more Caused by:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
>     ... 37 more

Comment: Did you try building this project with Gradle without Eclipse? (Execute this in the console "./gradlew build"?)

Comment: It seems to be failing at the point where it is trying to download Gradle distribution from https ://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.0-bin.zip. Seems to be something in your network environment prohibiting you from downloading from that url. You can try to download it yourself, unzip it and configure it in the Gradle preferences page manually. But it is likely you will then run into other problems since Gradle builds will also download things from the internet (dependencies).

Comment: What Kris recommended worked for me

Answer (score 10):

> I looked at the STS logs and saw that this was the issue
>   "org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not install
>   Gradle distribution from
>   'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.9-bin.zip'"

So from this is it is evident that STS is unable to download gradle distribution maybe due to proxy settings. The below approach worked for me -

In STS , navigate to Windows->Preferences->Gradle.
On the right hand pane , set folder under gradle distribution to path to gradle directory. I set it to "C:\software\gradle-2.6"

If you have network issues in downloading gradle distribution , use this approach.

Answer (score 4):

I notice the fact that this was posted a few months ago.  I hope that the issue has been resolved already.  But I would like to share what I did to solve this.

As Kris mentioned it had to do with the environment.  As the error suggests, it was unable to find valid certification path to the gradle distribution site.

Our company was somehow intercepting the certificate chain and making the root cert as the company CA.  My Company CA Cert was not present in jre/lib/security/cacerts keystore of the JRE used by my Eclipse.  I added my company CA cert to the keystore and it started working after that.  I believe that it is not limited to Gradle, it should have created problems with any other downloads using https!