# gradle error marker: Could not run build action using connection to gradle distribution

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am trying to import existing Gradle project in Eclipse Java EE IDE and I got this error:

> Could not run build action using connection to Gradle distribution
> 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-bin.zip'.

Please help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: I think this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57613247/could-not-install-gradle-distribution-from-https-services-gradle-org-distribu

Comment: even this has some solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53887356/eclipse-could-not-install-gradle-distribution-from-https-services-gradle-org

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while following the Coursera course "Introduction to Software Testing".

To fix it, I had to manually configure the JAVA_HOME variable and install an older version of Eclipse instead of 2021-03 version (Try Eclipse Photon for example).

Also, check if the version of jdk you are using is compatible with your Gradle. For my case, I had to use jdk 8.

Links :

- [To edit an environment variable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0917/inst_jdk_javahome_t/index.html)
- [An other stackoverflow topic related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32887623/errorcould-not-run-build-action-using-gradle-installation-gradle-2-4-android)